# How to disable down scrolling in ScrollPane in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, scroll, scrollpane

How to disable only down scrolling in `ScrollPane` when it reaches a specific `Vvalue`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the [vmaxProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#vmaxProperty) of the `ScrollPane`.

> The maximum allowable vvalue for this ScrollPane. Default value is 1.

By setting this property the scrollbar of the `ScrollPane` is rescaled, so the **bottom-most position of the scrollbar is actually the specified value**.

This will allow only the 40% of the vertical space to be scrolled:

```
scrollPane.setVmax(0.4);
```

**Another possiblity** is to interrupt down-scrolling by listening to the [vvalueProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#vvalueProperty) property of the `ScrollPane`.

With this approach, the scrollbar of the `ScrollPane` is stopped on a defined value, so **the bottom-most position is still 100%**.

```
final double maxDownScroll = 0.4;
scrollPane.vvalueProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
    if ((double) newVal > maxDownScroll)
        scrollPane.setVvalue(maxDownScroll);
});
```

**Note:** Both approaches is more generic than adding a filter to the `ScrollEvent` of the `ScrollPane` as they work in case of moving the scrollbar and also in case of scrolling with the mouse (`ScrollEvent` is only fired when the mouse wheel, tack pad or similar device is used).

Comment: Thanks, the other possibility is what I need. And thank you also for the note.

Answer (score 2):

OK I solved it. Code:

```
scrollPane.addEventFilter(ScrollEvent.SCROLL, new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ScrollEvent event) {
                    //"0.4 is my the specific value"
                    if(scrollPane.getVvalue() > 0.4) {
                        if (event.getDeltaY() < 0) {
                            event.consume();
                        }
                    }
             }
       });
```